# Running a Report with passing the number of pages to print and some values

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav, navision, cal

I have a Report in Microsoft Dynamics for printing customized labels.

The Report itself has one DataItem from the Items table. If you run the report, you can type in a item number and it prints a label on a selected thermo-printer.

Now, what i want to archive is, if i have an purchase order, i want to klick somwhere and navision should do something like this:

run report '50070' with item '10001' 6 copies of the label;
run report '50070' with item '10020' 3 copies of the label;

and so on.

I didn't find quite much about this topic. I tried to do it with a copy loop as mentioned in some posts but that didn't quite work that way i wanted it.

**Overview**

Report DataItems:

"Item" -> Record::Item

The following code is from the Item - OnAfterGetRecord() - Trigger

```
RecordNo := RecordNo + 1;
ColumnNo := ColumnNo + 1;

ItData[ColumnNo][1] := FORMAT("No.");
ItData[ColumnNo][2] := FORMAT(Description);
ItData[ColumnNo][3] := FORMAT(Var1);
ItData[ColumnNo][4] := FORMAT(Var2);
ItData[ColumnNo][5] := FORMAT("Unit Price");
ItData[ColumnNo][5] := FORMAT("Unit Price" * 1.19);


// finding own barcode first, if no own barcode found, take 
// the one you can get
barcodeStr := '';

recBarcode.SETFILTER("Item No.", "No.");
recBarcode.SETFILTER("Barcode No.", '99916*');

IF recBarcode.FINDFIRST THEN BEGIN
  barcodeStr := recBarcode."Barcode No.";
END ELSE BEGIN
  recBarcode.RESET;
  recBarcode.SETRANGE("Item No.", "No.");
  IF recBarcode.FINDFIRST THEN BEGIN
    barcodeStr := recBarcode."Barcode No.";
  END;
END;


// ask user, if to printing barcode is not a company own
// barcode, and let him decide if he whishes to print anyway
IF STRLEN(barcodeStr) = 13 THEN BEGIN
  IF (COPYSTR(barcodeStr, 1, 5) <> '99916') THEN BEGIN
    IF NOT CONFIRM('This item has NO company own barcode. Do you whish to print it anyway?', FALSE) THEN
      EXIT;
  END;

  // format the barcode-string to a format, that the barcode font
  // can understand and printing it properly for reading with a scanner
  EAN13 := DADA.GetPrintTextEAN13(barcodeStr);

END;

COMPRESSARRAY(ItData[ColumnNo]);

IF RecordNo = NoOfRecords THEN BEGIN
  FOR i := ColumnNo + 1 TO NoOfColumns DO
    CLEAR(Addr[i]);
  ColumnNo := 0;
END ELSE BEGIN
  IF ColumnNo = NoOfColumns THEN
    ColumnNo := 0;
END;


// finding a suiting logo for the barcode, user can choose between none, dd or ex
IF intLogoOption = 2 THEN BEGIN
  IF EXISTS ('N:\Labelprinting\dd\75x75\sw_for75x75.bmp') THEN
    TT.BLOBImport(BLOBRef, 'N:\Labelprinting\dd\75x75\sw_for75x75.bmp', FALSE);
END ELSE IF intLogoOption = 3 THEN BEGIN
  IF EXISTS ('N:\Labelprinting\ex\75x75\sw_for75x75.png') THEN
    TT.BLOBImport(BLOBRef, 'N:\Labelprinting\ex\75x75\sw_for75x75.png', FALSE);
END;

CALCFIELDS(Item.Picture);
```

My goal is, that the user can click once and select a printer once, and all labels get printed properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make a copy of your report with following dataitems:

```
Sales Header
--Sales Line
----Integer
------Item
```

Put your code to print one sticker into `Integer` dataitem. It will be executed number of times.
Filter `Sales Header` with number of your order. Link `Sales Line` to sales header, so report will run through all your items.

Put following code on `Sales line - OnAfterGetRecord`:

```
Integer.setrange("Number",1,"Sales Line"."Quantity");
```

Put item filtering into `Integer - OnPreDataItem`

```
Item.setrange("No.", "Sales Line"."Item No.");
```

It will launch sticker printing as many times as many items you have in your order for every line. This will also allow you to print stickers for bunch of orders.